# using HolidayCalendar

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a problem using a HolidayCalendar. It seems that the calendar is simply ignored.

Here my code (which mostly repeats code snippets from Quartz documentation):

```
public class Cron {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

            Calendar cbegin = Calendar.getInstance(), cend = Calendar.getInstance();
            cbegin.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
            cend.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);

            // exclude Nov 23 and Nov 24
            HolidayCalendar cln = new HolidayCalendar();

            cbegin.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);
            cln.addExcludedDate(new Date(cbegin.getTimeInMillis()));
            cbegin.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 24);
            cln.addExcludedDate(new Date(cbegin.getTimeInMillis()));

            scheduler.addCalendar("job1", cln, false, false);

            JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("job1").build();

            // trigger running once a day at 1 AM
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger10").forJob(job)
                .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0 1 * * ?"))
                .modifiedByCalendar("job1")
                .build();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            scheduler.start();

            // print fired times from Nov 21 to Nov 30
            cbegin.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
            cend.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

            Date dtnext = new Date(cbegin.getTimeInMillis()), dtend = new Date(cend.getTimeInMillis());
            do { 
                dtnext = trigger.getFireTimeAfter(dtnext); 
                System.out.println("Next... " + dtnext);
            } while(dtnext.before(dtend)); 

            try { Thread.sleep(3600000); } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}

            scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (Exception se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the results are:

```
 [java] Next... Thu Nov 22 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Fri Nov 23 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Sat Nov 24 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Sun Nov 25 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Mon Nov 26 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Tue Nov 27 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Wed Nov 28 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Thu Nov 29 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Fri Nov 30 01:00:00 CET 2012
 [java] Next... Sat Dec 01 01:00:00 CET 2012
```

As you can see, excluded dates Nov 23 and Nov 24 are still scheduled.

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the job won't be executed.

I modified a trigger to launch the job every minute and it's not executed on the excluded dates. But `trigger.getFireTimeAfter` still returns fired time on excluded date.

To solve a problem I need to check manually if the fired time is included in the calendar.